# Is there a way to automatically collapse the Script Documents section in solution explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

While in debug mode, the solution explorer has a Script Documents section.  It is expanded by default.  As the debugger runs, new `ScriptDocumentxxx poll.txt` files are added to this section.  As I am navigating the explorer files, the adding of these new line items causes the entire contents of the explorer to shift downward.  This is quite annoying if I am trying to find a file or trying to click something.  I can collapse the section manually, but I'd rather not have to do this all of the time.

[image]

Comment: I'm tempted to edit this and replace "quite annoying" with "very annoying"

Comment: did you already found a solution?

Comment: @Joel Nope.  Oddly, it eventually seemed to just resolve itself.  I am also using VS2015 now and it doesn't seem to have that problem.

Comment: I had the problem with visual studio 2015. Using any other browser than internet explorer fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 40):

Right click the projects you are interested in working on and click on 'Scope to this'. This will hide everything (Including the scripts folder) except those projects you selected.

[image: Visual Studio 'scope to this' example]

Comment: Why would I do this when I may as well just collapse the section?

Comment: You can select only the scripts you are interested in, the others will be hidden.

Comment: Just curious, how would you undo such an operation?

Comment: @mbomb007: Click the "Home" icon (third one by default, the one with a house pictogram) in the Solution explorer.

Comment: Upvoting this even though it does not answer the question, would love to know how to <b>permanently</b> collapse or even hide this folder!

Comment: This should be accepted since it answers the question. After limiting the scope, subsequent saves stay focused on this scope; which prevents Script Documents from opening since we've traversed beyond it. Good answer!

Comment: Marvelous! Except "right click the projectS" doesn't quite work because you can only do this on one item at a time. Instead what I did was make a root folder and moved every project into it, then scoped to the root folder. Now no more @%&@%&! scripts list. Yay!

Answer (score 29):

I got annoyed enough with this that I turned off JavaScript debugging.  If you are willing to go that far, the scripts are gone.

The path for turn of JS debugging is:

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge and IE) (Visual Studio 2017 and 2019)

Note: This method **does not** prevent you from stepping though JS in the Chrome inspection tools so you do not lose that ability.  You lose both the scripts (of course) and that new Chrome window that pops up when you launch the debugger.

**Visual Studio 2022 has this menu collapsed by default.**  Everyone can upgrade and rejoice as this question and it's answers go the way of the dinosaur.

Comment: This does it for me, and is easily reversible should I need to. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the reversibility is great and the only complaint I hear is too many new windows being generated by VS with this method.  I'd rather close a couple windows than deal with Solution Explorer jumping around.  So, that trade-off is going to always be a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: With the setting ON it will open a new instance, which closes when code is stopped. With the setting OFF it will open a new tab in the current instance, which won't close automatically. If you have multiple instances of your browser open, it can be a bit annoying tabbing through them to find the right one. I guess the answer to all of this is to setup a local site https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/323972/how-to-set-up-your-first-iis-web-site and just build your code, not run it.

Comment: I agree - this is super annoying. I wish they would just add an option to "Keep 'Script Documents' collapsed", then you can expand it whenever you need to (Do you ever?).

Comment: @Jonno I just made and edit because I tested and found that VS 2022 finally fixed this bug.  I have had this off for so many years that I didn't even think to check until recently. So, if you or anyone else can afford to, upgrading is an option.  I feel sorry for those who have legacy code or budgets that will prevent that from happening.

Comment: @joe did you have to do something magic to make that happen? I have VS2022 and it is still always open. It's a particular nightmare in Blazor projects because every .cs file registers as a script and so VS locks up for 10s at a time every time the browser loads or unloads the Blazor page.

Answer (score 5):

Right click then 'Scope to This' to hide everything but the project in the solution you want to view.

Click on the Home/House icon to reverse it.

Comment: Where do you find "Scope to This"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. One way is to create a visual studio add-in or extension which monitors the solution explorer tree and collapses the "script documents" -item if it is expanded.

If you need code samples and/or a fully functional add-in just let me know. You have Visual Studio 2013, ay? Is it the express edition or what?

Comment: Creating a whole add-on for VS just to auto-collapse a section is more trouble than it's worth.  The development time will most likely not offset the time I will save not having to collapse it myself.

Comment: That is very true but also that is the only solution I could come up with. Resharper has some feature(s) for collapsing solution items but I'm not sure if those can be automated. You can also enable silverlight debugging which should hide the script documents, but then you might not be able debug your scripts. Not sure about that.

Comment: This is basically what I've been looking for more and more as that "Script documents" folder started to grow in my project. I'd love to see a plugin like this for VS 2015, can't find anything that does it in the Visual Studio Gallery, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

This is confirmed bug in VS 2019. Just Microsoft is not so fast about fixing it.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/351537/provide-a-way-to-prevent-the-script-documents-fold.html