# How to default Visual Studio 2019 Script Documents to minimized?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I'm debugging an angular spa app. The problem is that the 'Script Documents' section in the Solution Explorer that appears when you are debugging is really annoying.

I know why this is here and why it is sometimes useful, but 99% of the time I want to hide it.

The JavaScript debugging is working fine and I do not want to turn it off. I just want Script Documents to remain closed.

This problem is made worse when my angular app keeps rebuilding as I make changes. If I close Script Documents, it just re-opens when the app rebuilds. There has to be a way to hide it.

I've seen similar questions before but I haven't seen any clear answers.

Comment: I don't think there currently is a way without disabling the script debugging. You can vote for the issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351537/provide-a-way-to-prevent-the-script-documents-fold.html) and maybe Microsoft will do something about it in the future. If you disable script debugging, you could still do the debugging in the browser's own developer tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to automatically collapse the Script Documents section in solution explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658749/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-collapse-the-script-documents-section-in-solutio)

Comment: @Cory Problem description looks similar but that question refers to VS2013. It's possible there is a solution for VS2019? I will experiment with the Scope To, to see if that offers any improvement or is more annoying.

Comment: @Cory The link to the issue at MS seems spot on. I did go ahead and vote for it. If anyone else reads this, please vote for it also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have not yet figured out a way to do it. It was an issue in VS going back many versions and remains an issue today.

The work around I went with is the same one suggested in 2014 for VS2013, which is to right click on the project in VS that you are most interested in and click Scope to This.

This is a crappy solution but it works if you are having the problem, but you can't easily get back to the other projects in your solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24116987/95041

As @Cory pointed out, there is a feature request. If this problem is affecting you, please upvote so it gets fixed.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351537/provide-a-way-to-prevent-the-script-documents-fold.html